# Does docker log-level impact logging driver or only logs of docker daemon?

Tags: docker, logging, systemd-journald

I have my logging driver setup of `journald`. Does the log-level config in `daemon.json` file impact logs when using a logging driver or only the container logs when using `docker logs <container_name>` ?

For example, docker and journald have documentation showing how to set log level/priority.

Docker's default setting is `info`: `log-level: info`.
With `journald` I can also use `-p` to set the log priority to `info`: `journalctl -p info`.

If my docker logging driver is `journald` with log priority set to `info`, do I even need to  worry about setting log-level to `info` in `daemon.json` file?

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you add little bit more info?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear. I added some more info above

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you confused the following concepts: logs of docker daemon, logs of container(s) and logs print with `journalctl` command.

1. The configuration in `docker.json` file impact logs of docker
   daemon.
2. The logs of container(s) would be only impacted by your application
   configuration in that container.
3. The command `journalctl -p` ONLY impact the logs showing on your
   screen, which means `-p` only do the filtering thing. No matter what
   level you've indicated, err or info, the logs are there already.

Hope this would be helpful.